# UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds shows unexpected value on phone, but not simulator

Tags: ios, uikit, retina, uiscreen, uiimageasset

I have an iPhone 6 that I'm developing code for in Xcode and I am having problems with reported screen size, my phone reports the wrong value!

**UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds:**

- Actual Value               - 375 x 667
- Reported Value (*Simulator*) - (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 667.0)
- Reported Value (*My Phone*)  - (0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 568.0)

**Problem:**

The values reported by my phone, an iPhone 6, are wrong. The phone is reporting values for the iPhone 5 !!

**Questions**

1. Why does my phone show the wrong values ???
2. How to fix this, and make it show the correct (375x667) values ?

Here is an illustration of the real values :

[image]

To note, this is SUCH a nuisance. My screen layouts are all messed up any time I try to used `UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds` :)

Comment: That seems to be related to auto scaling for iPhone 6. Do you have an iPhone6 launch screen image, or a launch screen storyboard?

Comment: my code is 100% programmatic, there is no storyboard. Could be the issue!! :)

Comment: http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions

Comment: Wow - Display Zoom!!!! THANK YOU - I'll research, resolve and hopefully conclude after work. THANK YOU!!!! :)

Comment: If you either add a launch screen image for iPhone6 or you add a launch screen storyboard, the UI will be drawn in native resolution on iPhone 6, fixing your problem